# reverse array list based on selected value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have an object array which looks like below

```
var arr = [{
   DocumentNo: '44',
   FileId: 1,
   FilenameWithExtension: 'aof.tif',
   DocTypeId: 1
}, {
   DocumentNo: '45',
   FileId: 2,
   FilenameWithExtension: 'aofd.tif',
   DocTypeId: 1
}, {
   DocumentNo: '46',
   FileId: 3,
   FilenameWithExtension: 'mdh.tif',
   DocTypeId: 1
}, {
   DocumentNo: '47',
   FileId: 4,
   FilenameWithExtension: 'zyl.tif',
   DocTypeId: 1
}, {
   DocumentNo: '48',
   FileId: 5,
   FilenameWithExtension: 'ddd.tif',
   DocTypeId: 3
}]
```

I want to reverse the array based on what user selects,

for example

> if user selects documentno in descending order the above list should
> starts with documentno ->(48,47,46,45,44)
>
> if user selects fileid in ascending order the above list should starts
> with FileId ->(1,2,3,4,5)
>
> if user selects fileid in descending order the above list should
> starts with FileId ->(5,4,3,2,1)

and so on.

how can I achieve the same, I googled this but couldn't found anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to sort this array of objects based on the `field` and `sorting order` passed by the user. If Yes, Here is the demo **:**

```js
var arr = [{
  DocumentNo: '44',
  FileId: 1,
  FilenameWithExtension: 'aof.tif',
  DocTypeId: 1
}, {
  DocumentNo: '45',
  FileId: 2,
  FilenameWithExtension: 'aofd.tif',
  DocTypeId: 1
}, {
  DocumentNo: '46',
  FileId: 3,
  FilenameWithExtension: 'mdh.tif',
  DocTypeId: 1
}, {
  DocumentNo: '47',
  FileId: 4,
  FilenameWithExtension: 'zyl.tif',
  DocTypeId: 1
}, {
  DocumentNo: '48',
  FileId: 5,
  FilenameWithExtension: 'ddd.tif',
  DocTypeId: 3
}]

const sortingObj = {
  field: 'FilenameWithExtension',
  sortBy: 'desc'
};

const res = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (sortingObj.field === 'FilenameWithExtension') {
    if (sortingObj.sortBy === 'aesc') {
      return (a[sortingObj.field] < b[sortingObj.field]) ? -1 : ((a[sortingObj.field] > b[sortingObj.field]) ? 1 : 0);
    } else {
      return (a[sortingObj.field] < b[sortingObj.field]) ? 1 : ((a[sortingObj.field] > b[sortingObj.field]) ? -1 : 0);
    }
  } else {
    return (sortingObj.sortBy === 'aesc') ?
      a[sortingObj.field] - b[sortingObj.field] :
    b[sortingObj.field] - a[sortingObj.field]
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hello @Rohit I can't use sorting on the below field  -> FilenameWithExtension

Comment: You can also have a look at the below fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/a0v7m9h8/

Comment: @TWMTV Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer. For string properties we have to use compare function differently. Hence, I wrote seperate logic for `FilenameWithExtension`

Comment: @TWMTV did you get a chance to test this updated solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example on how to do that with underscore

```
let arr = [{
   DocumentNo: '44',
   FileId: 1,
   FilenameWithExtension: 'aof.tif',
   DocTypeId: 1
}, {
   DocumentNo: '45',
   FileId: 2,
   FilenameWithExtension: 'aofd.tif',
   DocTypeId: 1
}, {
   DocumentNo: '46',
   FileId: 3,
   FilenameWithExtension: 'mdh.tif',
   DocTypeId: 1
}, {
   DocumentNo: '47',
   FileId: 4,
   FilenameWithExtension: 'zyl.tif',
   DocTypeId: 1
}, {
   DocumentNo: '48',
   FileId: 5,
   FilenameWithExtension: 'ddd.tif',
   DocTypeId: 3
}];
let userInput = "DocTypeId";
let result = _.sortBy(arr, userInput);
console.log(result);
```

```
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
```